# Using WS to query GetListItems with a greater than date and time query

Tags: list, 2007, web-services, query

So I am currently trying to pass the request formatted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <listName>000</listName>
      <viewName>000</viewName>
      <query><Query>
            <Where>
                <And>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Needs To Be Run</Value></Eq>
                <Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type="Date">2016-11-09 20:08:27</Value></Geq>
                </And>
                </Where>
            </Query></query>
      <viewFields></viewFields>
      <rowLimit>150</rowLimit>
      <QueryOptions></QueryOptions>
      <webID></webID>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

But currently it seems to ignore the time of the `created` field query. It seems to work with date, but not time.

How do i specify the time properly so that it filters things that it only shows items that were created after a specific time?

Comment: are you tried <Value Type="Datetime">

Comment: Yes. `Datetime` still does not seem to pass the time condition.

Comment: try to set time like this 2016-11-09T20:08:27Z

Comment: Still no luck. Using `<Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type='Datetime'>2016-11-09T23:08:27Z</Value></Geq>` still returns the record with the create date: 
`ows_Created='2016-11-09 11:07:46'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the date time value with this format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`with `IncludeTimeValue='True'` attribute ,  so it should like

```
<Geq><FieldRef Name='Created' /><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue='True'>2016-11-09T20:08:27Z</Value></Geq>
```

Comment: It looks like that worked! Thank you! I had no idea there was a `IncludeTimeValue` Property for this method. Can you please post your source for this answer?

Comment: I tried to use CAML Designer to test this you can download it from here https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/15/caml-designer/ , meanwhile, the source for this property is from Microsoft at  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms441886.aspx

Comment: This application is awesome. I was using "Postman" to send my XML and read XML manually before. Thanks again!